# Regex to parse an AVL device message

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string that comes from an AVL device

```
201412211732-34.20333,-56.23234 value1=pair1;value2=pair2;valueN=pairN
```

The format provided by the device manufacturer is

```
Fixed Part
----------
0-8               Date
9-12              Time
up to comma       Latitude
up to space       Longitude

Options Part
-------------
up to eq          Option Name
up to semicolon   Option Value

* The message can have 0 or more Options.
** The last option could end not with a semicolon.
```

I wrote an ugly function to parse this message. I'm not a regex guy, but I'd like use a regular expression. I can appreciate its simplicity.

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

btw: in javascript.

EDIT:

I want get optional part too, but splited as key-pair, is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups to capture the substrings you want.

```
^(\d{8})(\d{4})([^,\n]+),([^\s\n]+)\s?(?:[^\n=]+=[^\n;]+)?(?:;(?:[^\n=]+=[^\n;]+))*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/7)

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `\d{8}` Matches exactly 8 digits.
- `[^\s\n]` Negated character class which matches any character but of space or a newline character.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Use this regex if you want to capture also the optional values.

```
^(\d{8})(\d{4})([^,\n]+),([^\s\n]+)\s?((?:[^\n=]+=[^\n;]+)?(?:;(?:[^\n=]+=[^\n;]+))*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX3sD2/8)

Comment: match1, does not match optional values. almost in demo.

Comment: did you want to capture the optional values?

Comment: you could split the last captured group by semicolon to get the key value pair.

Answer (score 1):

Avinash Raj answer is good, i went with:

```
^(\d{8})(.{4})([^,]+),([^\s]+)\s(.*)$
```

and left the val=pairs alone as there could be 0 or more options. I'd split these in `js` on the `;` then loop to get the data. `js regex` doesn't have recursion :(

The date, time, lat and long are in captured groups \1, \2, \3 and \4 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the prefix first and then do a loop over the suffix:

```js
var str = '201412211732-34.20333,-56.23234 value1=pair1;value2=pair2;valueN=pairN';
var prefix = str.match(/(.{8})(.{4})([^,]+),([^ ]+)/);
var options = {};

if (prefix) {
  var re = /([^=]+)=([^;]+);?/g,
  suffix = str.substring(prefix[0].length),
  item;

  while (item = re.exec(suffix)) {
    options[item[1]] = item[2];
  }
}

console.log(prefix, options);
```